# Creating an update trigger is causing an error

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, triggers

There are two triggers; the first trigger is running perfectly but I want to add another trigger to the same table.

The second trigger is an `after update` trigger. Please check and tell my is it right or wrong or if we run this trigger it will run perfect or not

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[tr_issueBook] 
ON [dbo].[IssueBooks] 
FOR INSERT
AS 
BEGIN
    DECLARE @IsbnNumber varchar(255)

    SELECT @IsbnNumber = ISBN_Number FROM inserted 

    UPDATE searchBooks 
    SET tbl_numberOfCopies = tbl_numberOfCopies - 1  
    WHERE tbl_IsbnBooks = @IsbnNumber
END

/******2nd Trigger ******/
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[tr_issueBook2]
ON [dbo].[IssueBooks]
AFTER UPDATE
AS 
BEGIN
    DECLARE @IsbnNumber varchar(255)

    SELECT @IsbnNumber = BookTitle FROM updated

    UPDATE searchBooks 
    SET tbl_numberOfCopies = [tbl_numberOfCopies] + 1 
    WHERE tbl_bookTitle = @IsbnNumber
END
```

My second trigger is throwing an error:

> invalid object name updated

Comment: We can't tell you whether it is perfect or not - thats your job to test it and see if it meets your needs. Although I can tell you that none of those triggers will work. Inserted is a table and as such can contain multiple (or 0) rows. You need to handle that in a set based manner (not a procedural manner). And also you don't necessarily need 2 triggers - you can combine the logic into a single trigger - which may or may not perform better.

Comment: Refer to this [often-shared link](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2019/05/the-silent-bug-i-find-in-most-triggers/)

Comment: @DaleK When I insert something into a table so first trigger will run perfectly but when I update in the same table so I want to increase +1. it is possible

Comment: @DaleK First Trigger running perfectly I want to add update trigger in same manner

Comment: If you insert 2 rows, only 1 (essentially random) `IsbnNumber`  will be updated. Try it and see.

Comment: @DaleK in my project 1st trigger running perfectly so why you tell me ^^^No it isn'... My Query is I want to add another trigger

Comment: @DaleK lets finish this talk, please check my 1st trigger which is inserted trigger, use same values please give me update trigger in same manner I will put on my style.

Comment: There just isn't an `updated` pseudo table to be used in an AFTER UPDATE trigger - only `Inserted` (with the **new values** after the update), and `Deleted` (with the old values before the update)

Answer (score 2):

Both of your triggers are currently broken because you do not handle the case when the `Inserted` pseudo table has more or less rows than 1. You need to treat the `Inserted` pseudo table like you would any other table and perform set based operations on it instead of procedural logic.

```
-- INSERT Trigger - using the Inserted pseudo table
update searchBooks set
    tbl_numberOfCopies = tbl_numberOfCopies - 1
where tbl_IsbnBooks in (select ISBN_Number from Inserted);
```

```
-- UPDATE Trigger - also using the Inserted pseudo table (There is no Updated table)
update searchBooks set
    tbl_numberOfCopies = tbl_numberOfCopies + 1
where tbl_IsbnBooks in (select ISBN_Number from Inserted);
```

I highly recommend reading the [Official Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/triggers/use-the-inserted-and-deleted-tables?view=sql-server-ver15).

Comment: Yes You Got my Point but second trigger should be after update. so how to write?

Comment: in my second triigger it gives me an error invalid object name updated

Comment: I solved that for you in my answer also. Again the official docs explain all that.

Comment: Thank You for your replying. But when I ask question it will block me for 7 days. Why its happened